# Reference request： formal GAGA for schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Could someone provide a precise reference for formal GAGA for schemes?
I found some papers dealing with stacks, but I want an account for schemes.

Comment: EGA III Chap. 5?

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at FGA or the stacks project

Comment: From http://stacks.math.columbia.edu: "The Stacks Project now consists of:...5734 pages..." That may not be what the OP had in mind when using the word "precise".

Comment: It is also unclear if "FGA" refers to the Bourbaki exposes of Grothendieck or the book "FGA Explained" or both (and in each case, it would be helpful to make the reference more precise).